Why can Process Explorer show (some) function names, without any pdb file
Lab env:

A realtively fresh Win10.22H2 instance.
Process Explorer 17.06 .

ProcExp Configure Symbols like this:

I use the default dbghelp.dll of C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dbghelp.dll .
Now, I check into notepad.exe's [Threads] Tab.


You see, some modules shows function name along:

win32k.sys!EngSaveFloatingPointState
USER32.dll!GetMessageW
KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart

Other modules do not:

ntoskrnl.exe
win32kfull.sys
notepad.exe

I search the hard drive for .pdb files, there is none, except two WindowsAppSdk.AppxDeploymentExtensions.Desktop-EventLog-Instrumentation.pdb(1.3MB around, one for x86 and one for x64). Sure we can neglect this one, because it should have nothing to do with the traditional notepad process.
Now my question/baffle is: Since there is no win32k.pdb, user32.pdb, how can Process Explorer come up with function names like EngSaveFloatingPointState, GetMessageW etc?
I know, for a decent system hacker, he would use another flavor of dbghelp.dll from Windows Driver Kit(WDK), and see that win32k.pdb, user32.pdb being downloaded to d:\WebSymbols directory.
There are quite some mysteries regarding dbghelp.dll. Please answer my first baffle as first step.
